# How to deplay a Java application using a Microsoft Access database

Tags: java, ms-access, odbc

I need to know a how to deploy my Java application using a Microsoft Access database. The database is only for localhost what steps do I need to do when I deploy it

1. do I need to again set up connection from odbc window to my access database
2. or do I need to write a specific code for that also is yes do I need to do it in

   ```
   con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Cable_Software");
   ```

And also i am using access 2013 does it have any effects when running it on access 2010 or below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to set your ODBC source. if you are using Windows 7 Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools has ODBC in it. Enter Cable_Software as a Data Source using MS Access Driver.